# Происходит замена предыдущего вывода (php, js)

Tags: php, javascript, замена

Начнем с того, что мне нужно вывести комментарии на странице. Первые 5 комментов показываются, а остальные я активирую через ID, добавляя по 10 комментариев

project.php:

```
<div class='pview-comm-more'></div>
<div class="text-aligndd"><a href="#" id="showmorecomm">Вывести еще комментарии</a></div>



if( $show_more_comm )
                    {

                        ?>
                    var numb = 0.6;
                        $("#showmorecomm").bind("click", function(){
                            loadProjComment(numb,'<?=$proj['id'];?>','.pview-comm-more');
                            $(this).show();
                            numb+=1;
                            return false
                        });

                        <?php

                        }
                        ?>
```

Это basic.js

```
function loadProjComment(num, projid, contid)
{
        var post_comm_str = "projid=" + projid + "&pi=" + num + "&pn=10";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: req_ajx_host+"ajx/projcomms/",
            data: post_comm_str,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data){

                try
                {
                    $(contid).html(data);
                }
                catch(e1)
                {
                    // Some errors occure while retieving city list so do nothing
                    $(contid).html("Error loading data...");
                }

            }
        });
}
```

Из basic.js передаются в ajxController.class.php

```
public function action_projcomms(){
        $projid = $this->getReqParam("projid", 0);
        $pi = $this->getReqParam("pi", 0);
        $pn = $this->getReqParam("pn", 0);

        if ($pi > 0 && $pn > 0) {
            $catLib = new Catalog($this->db, $this->LangId);
            $coms = $catLib->Item_Comments($projid, 1, $pi, $pn);

            $html = $this->view->reqlist_comments($coms);

            $this->view->render_html($html);
        }
}
```

Потом добавляется 10 сообщений в методе

```
public function reqlist_comments($coms){

    for( $i=0; $i<count($coms); ++$i ) {
        ($coms[$i]['pic']) ? $psrc = (WWWHOST.$coms[$i]['pic']) : $psrc = (WWWHOST.'img/no-pic.png');
        ?><div class="pview-comment-it pview-comm">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3 pview-comm-border">
                                    <div class="pview-comm-usr">

        <a href="<?=$this->Page_BuildUrl("users", "viewrev/".$coms[$i]['author_id'])?>"><img class="usr-comm-pic" src='<?=$psrc?>' alt="<?=( $coms[$i]['account_type'] == USR_TYPE_PERS ? $coms[$i]['name'].' '.$coms[$i]['fname'] : $coms[$i]['orgname'] )?>" title="<?=( $coms[$i]['account_type'] == USR_TYPE_PERS ? $coms[$i]['name'].' '.$coms[$i]['fname'] : $coms[$i]['orgname'] )?>" height="50px" width="50px">
                                    <span class="pview-usr-ico pview-com-usr"><?=( $coms[$i]['account_type'] == USR_TYPE_PERS ? $coms[$i]['name'].' '.$coms[$i]['fname'] : $coms[$i]['orgname'] )?></span></a>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-7 col-lg-10">
                                <div class="pview-comm-txt">
                                    <div class="pview-comment-msg proj-size-fix"><?=$coms[$i]['content']?></div>
                                    <span class="pview-comment-dt proj-size-data"><?=$this->localize->get("projview", "dt-comment").': '.$coms[$i]['add_dt']?></span>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            </div>
        <?php
    }

}
```

Но при повторном нажатии на надпись "Показать еще комментарии" у меня выведенные раньше 10 комментов заменяются на новую партию комментариев. Как сделать так что бы каждый раз вывод не заменял предыдущий?

Comment: небольшое отступление. а почему комментарии запрашиваете методом `POST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
$(contid).html(data);
```

На

```
$(contid).append(data);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 1):

`$(contid).html(data);` => `$(contid).append(data);`